# NSDate with current date components and a TimeString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdatecomponents, date-conversion

I have a timeString like this: `11:00:00.000+0000`

I would to generate a NSDate from this time string with:

- Day: current day value;
- Month: current month value;
- Year: current year value;

and as time components these rapresented from the TimeString.
I tried this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
    return [dateFormatter dateFromString:aTimeString];
```

to create a NSDate from this TimeString. But, to set the current date to this generated NSDate is there some simple way or I need to set every date component?

Answer (score 0):

The method `dateFromString:` uses the values of the components in your NSString. 
To create a NSDate object with the current values you use `[NSDate date]`. 
You can then use NSDateFormtter and dateFormat to set the format you want on that date, and you can get a string from that formatted date with `[formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]`